# How to parse a row(s)

Tags: javascript

Currently, I retrieve a row(s) from MySQL with a query, and then I emit that row directly (using socket.io) back to the html page. At the html page, I can't seem to access the fields of the row.

For example, (given a row that has field 'id')

```
<html>
    <script>
    //*some code that grabs the rows here*
    for( var row in rows){
         var id = row.id;     
         //do something   
    }
    </script>
</html>
```

In that case, 'id' would be undefined. What is the proper way to handle the rows in this case? (If I do console.log(rows) before emission in the node file, it prints the correct data.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your case

```
for( var row in rows){
    var id = row.id;     
    //do something   
}
```

`row` is a `String` or `Key` of Object `rows`

you need to do

```
rows[row].id
```

**How for...each works**

```
var obj = {
    name:'test',
    age:12
}

for(each in obj) {
    console.log('each: ', each)
    console.log('value of each: ', obj[each])
}
//output
each: name
value of each: test
each: age
value of each: 12
```

Answer (score 1):

`row` in your case is the key of an object/array.

So you need to do:

```
rows[row].id
```